# Sequelize error when using sequelize.fn in where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The Sequelize docs show:

```
Post.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', sequelize.col('status')), 6)
});
```

My query:

```
models.appointment.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('char_length', Sequelize.col('department')), 6)
})
```

Is throwing an error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value Where {
  attribute: Fn { fn: 'lower', args: [ [Object] ] },
  comparator: '=',
  logic: 6 }
```

With Sequelize v4.42.x (newest) and mysql. Why would this query be throwing an error like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it? and let me know. I found a solution at this [post](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10394#issuecomment-458242062)

```
models.appointment.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('char_length', Sequelize.col('department')), '=',6)
})
```

Comment: nice! I feel like that needs to be spelled out better in the docs. Thanks much

Comment: I agree. Currently, the document of sequelize is very simple, not cover all case. We need more case study

Comment: You can also use Raw where query like -

where: { $and: Sequelize.literal("(char_length(department) = 6)") },